# My function is only displaying one tuple from my database , how can I make it display all of them?

Tags: python, sqlite

this is my code but my function is only displaying one booking on the screen

```
            c = conn.cursor()  
            c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM details")
            bookings = c.fetchall()
            print(bookings)
            print_bookings = ''
            for booking in bookings:
                print_bookings = str(booking) + "\n"
                
            viewbookings= Label(Data.Display, text=print_bookings)
            viewbookings.grid (row=0,column=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting print_bookings with each loop iteration. You can concatenate all responses for example (+=):

```
for booking in bookings:
    print_bookings += str(booking) + "\n"
```

Or same one-liner (but no extra \n at the end):

```
print_bookings = '\n'.join(map(str, bookings))
```